# Eigenfunctions of the Legendre transform

Tags: transformation, eigenfunctions

Does the Legendre transform have eigenfunctions? If so, what are they?

(By eigenfunction, I mean a function whose transform is equal to itself times a constant.)

Comment: On what space do you define the Legendre transform?

Comment: Moreover, the Legendre transform is not linear...